# Install Ubuntu 18.04 Server with Hardware RAID1 configuration on Intel Nuc Skull Canyon

Tags: server, 18.04, uefi, raid

I am trying to install Ubuntu Server 18.04 LTS server with hardware RAID1 on Skull Canyon (NUC6i7KYK). SSDs for RAID are two identical Samsung 970 Pro 1Tb.

1. In first step i updated bios of Skull Canyon
2. In second step i configured RAID1 on bios

[image] [image][image]
 3. Then I boot Ubuntu Server 18.04 LTS in UEFI mode and install Ubuntu however when I try to manually arrange partition but it dose not detect any volume [image]

So, what is issue here? any ideas?

P.S: I am new at RAID.

P.P.S: I found that during bootup time i saw following output:
[image]